# Compile Error with Eluna - QueryResult.cpp

Tags: c++, cmake, azerothcore, eluna-lua-engine

I am running the dockerized version of the latest build.

My issue is that when I add the [mod-eluna-lua-engine](https://github.com/azerothcore/mod-eluna-lua-engine) module, I receive the following error:

```
[ 16%] Building CXX object src/common/CMakeFiles/common.dir/Database/Implementation/WorldDatabase.cpp.o
/azerothcore/src/common/Database/QueryResult.cpp:189:18: fatal error: out-of-line definition of 'GetFieldName' does not match any declaration in 'ResultSet'
char* ResultSet::GetFieldName(uint32 index) const
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [src/common/CMakeFiles/common.dir/Database/QueryResult.cpp.o] Error 1
```

I've searched and haven't found any similar reports, so it has to be me, right? What is it that I am missing?

Edit:
Running cmake is resulting in the following:

```
CMake Error at src/cmake/platform/unix/settings.cmake:22 (configure_file):
  configure_file attempted to configure a file:
  /mnt/wowstuff/server/cmake_uninstall.cmake into a source directory.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/cmake/macros/CheckPlatform.cmake:15 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:90 (include)
```

Final edit: after properly rerunning cmake, copying the build files as needed, then deleting the build cache and rerunning acore-docker-build, the compile worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

The resolution to this problem was to 1. Properly re-run cmake, building to another folder, and copying the build files into my Azerothcore environment. Once I had done that and deleted the docker/build/cache directory, I was able to successfully compile and run.

Hope it helps another new-to-c-person out there!